# Django: How can I render my formsets without having every single field in a <p> (or any other) element without losing the management form?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm rendering my model formset in the following way:

```html
<form method="POST" class="note-form">
    {{ formset.management_data }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

However, this renders every single field in every form in a `<p>` element, which I don't want. It's unpacked like this:

```html
<form method="POST" class="note-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"...>
    <input type="hidden" name="form-TOTAL-FORMS"...>
    <input type="hidden" name="form-INITIAL-FORMS"...>
    <input type="hidden" name="form-MIN-NUM-FORMS"...>
    <input type="hidden" name="form-MAX-NUM-FORMS"...>
    <p>
        <textarea ...></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input ...>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input ...>
    </p>
    <p>
        <textarea ...></textarea>
    </p>
    ...and so on...
</form>
```

Instead, I want something that would be rendered like this

```html
<form method="POST" class="note-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"...>
    <input type="hidden" name="form-TOTAL-FORMS"...>
    <input type="hidden" name="form-INITIAL-FORMS"...>
    <input type="hidden" name="form-MIN-NUM-FORMS"...>
    <input type="hidden" name="form-MAX-NUM-FORMS"...>
    <div ...>
        <textarea ...></textarea>
        <input ...>
        <input ...>
    </div>
    <div ...>
        <textarea ...></textarea>
        <input ...>
        <input ...>
    </div>
    ....and so on....
```

That is, each single form in a div element. Now, I tried doing the following

```html
    <form method="POST" class="note-form">

        {{ formset.management_data }}
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for form in formset %}
            <div>
                {{ form }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </form>
```

This renders the formset the way I want it. The problem with this is that, when I do it, the management data disappears and I get the error 'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with'.

I found something a bit similar [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/#manually-rendered-can-delete-and-can-order), but still, this is not working for me. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<table>
    {{ formset.as_table }}
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had tried this, and it looks a bit more organized. However, this still doesn't join the fields in each form in a single element (preferably a div). Do you know why what I tried makes the management data disappear?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, if the formset is not rendered with `{{ formset.as_p }}`, `{{ formset.as_table }}` or similar, the management data is not rendered automatically. It has to be rendered manually.

```
    {{ formset.management_data }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="notes-pane">
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in formset %}
            <div>
                {{ form }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </div>
</form>
```